# Apex SOQL/SOSL Parser

Tags: apex, soql, sosl, parser

Is there an Apex-based DML, SOQL and SOSL parser?  I see the only way this could happen is during the time of deployment, I can use DeployDetails to get the list of SOQLs.  Any pointers on how I can get DML, SOQL and SOSL statements, both static and dynamic?

Comment: Just to add, Symbol table would give information about methods, attributes and access modifies for a class, but not DMLs, SOQLs or SOSL.

Comment: You want to do this with native Apex? If you were off platform you could look at using the [Apex Language Server](https://www.salesforce.com/video/1765282/).

Comment: That is right, I'm looking at Native Apex.  Hmmm.. Thank you @DanielBallinger